# Complicated query that compares subselects

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-8.0

I have pretty hard query to write and I have no idea how to approach this.

I also have no idea for my question title, so if someone has good idea how to describe my problem - please suggest it.

---

I'm working on software for stock management and I need a query that will show all differences between "Expected groups" and "Inventoried group".

There is `inventory_item_stocktakings` table that holds data about Stocktaking.
It is related with `inventory_item_groups` table, which is a table used to group `inventory_items` for many different purposes.
Each "Stocktaking" can be made of multiple `inventory_item_stocktakings` records. For example this is a "Stocktaking" performed on 2 source groups (39, 40) with "Expected items" and there is one result group (41) for "Inventoried items".

[image]

To get differences between "Expected items" and "Inventoried items" I have written this query:

```
select * from
    (select inventory_item_group_id, inventory_item_id from inventory_item_group_items where inventory_item_group_id in (39, 40)) e
RIGHT JOIN 
    (select inventory_item_group_id, inventory_item_id from inventory_item_group_items where inventory_item_group_id in (41)) i
on e.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
where e.inventory_item_id is null
UNION 
select * from
    (select inventory_item_group_id, inventory_item_id from inventory_item_group_items where inventory_item_group_id in (39, 40)) e
LEFT JOIN 
    (select inventory_item_group_id, inventory_item_id from inventory_item_group_items where inventory_item_group_id in (41)) i
on e.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
where i.inventory_item_id is null
```

This is the result "Stocktaking" performed on 39 and 40 grops, with results stored in 41 group and there are 6 missing items and 2 unexpected items.

[image]

However this cannot be parametrized (notice hardcoded 39, 40 and 41 group id's).

How can extend this query to show all differences from all existing stoctakings?

Comment: Does `41` need to be duplicated in the `inventoried_items_group_id` column? I realise that you are comparing a set of two groups with a set of one and that you chose to store an expected ID and an inventoried ID on the same row for some reason, but then how would you be comparing e.g. 3 against 2? Or 2 against 3 for that matter? How would you decide which ID to duplicate? Wouldn't it be easier to use nulls (as in `(39, 41), (40, NULL)`)? Even better, store all IDs in the same column and have an additional indicator column called `is_inventoried` (0 = expected, 1 = inventoried). Just a thought.

Comment: @AndriyM Well, there will be never more than 1 group to be compared in the second set. This single group is a result of stocktaking process taken on `n` groups. I should use `=` instead of `IN` on the second subquery to indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you think of a Venn diagram, you are fetching the items that in one table and not the other?

I see no advantage, and a significant performance disadvantage, in having that query the extra layer of `SELECTs`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ...
        FROM a
        RIGHT JOIN b ON ...
        WHERE ... ) ab
```

can be simplified to

```
 ( SELECT ...
        FROM a
        RIGHT JOIN b ON ...
        WHERE ... ) ab
```

I don't know if the `UNION` can be eliminated, but it can be sped up by changing from `UNION DISTINCT` (the default) to `UNION ALL`.

**More**

I think this is equivalent, after shortening the names:

```
SELECT  e.x, e.id, i.x, i.id
    FROM        items e  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  e.x in (39, 40)
    RIGHT JOIN  items i  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  i.x in (41)
    where  e.id is null
UNION 
SELECT  e.x, e.id, i.x, i.id
    FROM        items e  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  e.x in (39, 40)
    LEFT JOIN   items i  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  i.x in (41)
    WHERE  i.id is null
```

But perhaps you did not want the NULLs to show, so (changing only the SELECT list):

```
SELECT  i.x, i.id 
    FROM        items e  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  e.x in (39, 40)
    RIGHT JOIN  items i  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  i.x in (41)
    where  e.id is null
UNION 
SELECT  e.x, e.id
    FROM        items e  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  e.x in (39, 40)
    LEFT JOIN   items i  ON  e.id = i.id  AND  i.x in (41)
    WHERE  i.id is null
```

(I never use `RIGHT JOIN` because my head does not turn around like an owl's, so I don't know if I am using it properly.)

Comment: Yes, I need to find differences. Items that are in both "item groups" are not important. But these are not tables. It is the same table, just different "item group" id's. Regarding extra layer - I'm using it for "where ... is null". How can I take only differences without that `SELECT * FROM () where ... is null` around my subquery that does right join?

Comment: I added some more.

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN` after `where  e.x in (39, 40)`?

Comment: The idea is clear (more or less) but the syntax is wrong.  A join can't follow the `WHERE` clause. Nor can you have more than one `WHERE` per `SELECT` (at the same level, that is).

Comment: @AndriyM - Which query are you saying has a syntax problem?

Comment: The queries in the last two code blocks. You have `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... RIGHT JOIN ... WHERE ... ON ... WHERE ...` there. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Thanks, @AndriyM -- I was being quite blind.

Comment: I got the idea about removing "outer" select, however it is there beacause I was thinking forward. I want to join all these results with something else.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get the hardcoded numbers from a subquery with join, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

I am not sure about this subquery, if it is correctly joined:

```
-- ...
SELECT
    expected_items_group_id
FROM
    inventory_stocktakings s2
where
    s2.expected_items_group_id = esub.inventory_item_group_id
)
-- ...
```

And here is full query:

```
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        inventory_item_group_id,
        inventory_item_id
    from
        inventory_item_group_items esub
    where
        inventory_item_group_id in (
        SELECT
            expected_items_group_id
        FROM
            inventory_stocktakings s2
        where
            s2.expected_items_group_id = esub.inventory_item_group_id
        )) e
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    select
        inventory_item_group_id,
        inventory_item_id
    from
        inventory_item_group_items isub
    where
        inventory_item_group_id in (
        SELECT
            inventoried_items_group_id
        FROM
            inventory_stocktakings s3
        where
            s3.inventoried_items_group_id = isub.inventory_item_group_id)) i
on
    e.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
where i.inventory_item_id is null
UNION ALL
select
    *
from
    (
    select
        inventory_item_group_id,
        inventory_item_id
    from
        inventory_item_group_items esub
    where
        inventory_item_group_id in (
        SELECT
            expected_items_group_id
        FROM
            inventory_stocktakings s2
        where
            s2.expected_items_group_id = esub.inventory_item_group_id
        )) e
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
    select
        inventory_item_group_id,
        inventory_item_id
    from
        inventory_item_group_items isub
    where
        inventory_item_group_id in (
        SELECT
            inventoried_items_group_id
        FROM
            inventory_stocktakings s3
        where
            s3.inventoried_items_group_id = isub.inventory_item_group_id)) i
on
    e.inventory_item_id = i.inventory_item_id
where e.inventory_item_id is null
```

So far, with single `inventory_stocktakings` record pair it works the same as with hardcoded numbers.

Now I have to add my `inventory_stocktakings` to the final result set.